# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 keeps crashing on startup on WIndows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2010

I just installed Windows 8.1 on my PC and i discovered that each time i start my Visual Studio 2010 it keeps crashing as soon as it starts loading.

I also discovered a game, PES 2016 doesnt start up also and gives a prompt saying Application Error with the error code 0x000007b.

Comment: unfourtunately,  0x000007b literally means "The application was unable to start correctly", so no real diagnostic info is available. Check your application event log, to see if there are additional, more specific messages. you may also want to try executing VS from within an elevated command prompt, to see if any error messages are displayed in the console. Try running VS in safemode with  `devenv.exe /SafeMode`.

Comment: @FrankThomas How do i execute VS within an elevated command prompt.

Comment: see here for how to open CMD as admin: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/f/elevated-command-prompt.htm  

then run `cd c:\the\path\to\your\VS\install\` and finally the command I provided above: `devenv.exe`. add the /SAFEMODE switch if desired.

Comment: From MSDN, [{Bad Image} %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should run [devenv.exe/PES from inside Dependency Walker (depends.exe)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx). When you run the Profiler (F7), depends.exe shows and error which DLL is has issues.